# Unable to run React and Node application with docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run **React.js** and **Node.js** (**Express.js**) application into docker container. So far I have create a **Dockerfile** for React application and another **Dockerfile** for **Node.js** application.

**Dockerfile(React app)**

```
FROM alpine:3.11

RUN apk add --update nodejs npm

RUN mkdir /client
WORKDIR /client

RUN npm install
COPY . /client

RUN npm install --global http-server

CMD [ "http-server"]
```

**Dockerfile(Node app)**

```
FROM alpine:3.11

RUN apk add --update nodejs npm

RUN mkdir /server
WORKDIR /server

COPY ./package.json /package.json
COPY ./package-lock.json /package-lock.json

RUN npm install

COPY . /server

CMD [ "node", "server.js"]
```

I have also created a **docker-compose** like this -

```
version: '3'

services:
    server:
        build: ./backend
        expose: 
            - 8080
        environment: 
            API_HOST: "http://localhost:8080"
            APP_SERVER_PORT: 8080
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
        volumes: 
            - ./client
        command: node server.js
    client:
        build: ./build
        environment: 
            -REACT_APP_PORT: 8081
        expose: 
            - 8081
        ports: 
            - 8081:8081
        volumes: 
            - ./server
        links: 
            - server
        command: http-server
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my configuration when I run **docker-compose up** it throws an error as show below -

```
Error: Error loading shared library /server/node_modules/hummus/binding/hummus.node: Exec format error
server_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1021:18)
server_1  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
server_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
server_1  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
server_1  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
server_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/server/node_modules/hummus/hummus.js:5:31)
server_1  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
server_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
server_1  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
server_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
pdf_spliter_server_1 exited with code 1
client_1  | Starting up http-server, serving ./
client_1  | Available on:
client_1  |   http://127.0.0.1:8080
client_1  |   http://172.26.0.3:8080
client_1  | Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

Comment: Can you try deleting the node_modules folder and install again?

Comment: The `volumes:` declarations are overwriting the contents of the images, including binaries in the `node_modules` trees, with incompatible things from your host.  (Are you on a MacOS or Windows host?)  Try deleting the `volumes:` declarations.  (You also don't need `expose:`, `links:`, or `command:`, especially when they duplicate directives in the Dockerfile.)

Comment: I am on mac OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a `volumes:` declaration that names a host path, the entire contents of that host path replace whatever was built into the image.  You mention in a comment that you're on MacOS; in this environment, Docker runs in a hidden Linux VM, so you're mounting a MacOS `node_modules` directory to run in a Linux environment, which leads to the error you're getting.

The standard Docker model is that an image contains an entire packaged application and all of its dependencies.  You should be able to independently run an image without separately needing the application source code.  Your Dockerfiles have lines like `COPY . /server` which in fact copy the entire application tree in.

This means that you can delete the `volumes:` lines from your `docker-compose.yml` file to use the code built into the image.  You can also remove a number of other options (`links:` and `expose:` aren't used in modern Docker; `command:` just duplicates a Dockerfile setting).  That would leave you with

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    server:
        build: ./backend
        environment: 
            API_HOST: "http://localhost:8080"
            APP_SERVER_PORT: 8080
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
    client:
        build: ./build
        ports: 
            - 8081:3000
```

You also need to make sure you have a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) that excludes `node_modules` from the Docker build context.  This will avoid overwriting the results of the `RUN npm install` step and reduce the overhead of running `docker build`.

Comment: If I remove volume then how would the changes made on the source code of host would be replicated inside the container?

Comment: Re-run `docker-compose up --build`.